# i want aggregate in array into array mongodb

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, aggregate

i have three different collection and each table connected with unique objectid.
this is mongodb database..

```
collection1 => cate = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835"),
    "name" : "home & kitchen"
},{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23836"),
    "name" : "shoes"
}

collection2 => subcate = {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23890"),
    "cate" : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835"),
    "name" : "dish"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23891"),
    "cate" : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835"),
    "name" : "dish 2"
}

collection3 => petacate ={
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff983abdcb22e2f9fd238c8"),
    "subcate" : ObjectId("5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23890"),
    "cate" : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835"),
    "name" : "small dish"
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ff983abdcb22e2f9fd238c7"),
    "subcate" : ObjectId("5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23890"),
    "cate" : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835"),
    "name" : "big dish"
}
```

i am bigner in this language and i want this type of result in aggregate. i am trying to solve this but i can't.

collection1 `_id` is connected with collection2 `cate`, and both collection1 & collection2 connected with collection3 in sequence `cate` & `subcate`

```
cat: {
        _id: "5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835",
        name: "home & kitchen",
        subcate: [
            {
                _id: "5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23890",
                cate: "5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835",
                name: "dish",
                petacate: [
                    {
                        _id: "5ff983abdcb22e2f9fd238c8",
                        subcate: "5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23890",
                        cate: "5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835",
                        name: "small dish"
                    },
                    {
                       _id : ObjectId("5ff983abdcb22e2f9fd238c7"),
                       subcate : ObjectId("5ff9837ddcb22e2f9fd23890"),
                       cate : ObjectId("5ff98328dcb22e2f9fd23835"),
                       name : "big dish"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you join collection you have to use `$lookup`. There are two kind of lookup. both are used here.

- first `$lookup` is the [standard lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#syntax) to join collections with one condition which is `_id` of `cate` is equal to `cate` of `subcate`
- `$unwind` to deconstruct the array. (Array to object)
- second `$lookup` is the [uncorrelated lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries) to use multiple condition. When you use this kind of lookup, you need to use `$expr` in `$match` stage. Using `$match`, we conditionally checked `subcate` and `cate`.
- `$group` is to reconstruct the deconstructed array

Here is the script

```
db.cate.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "subcate",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "cate",
      "as": "subcate"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$subcate" },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "petacate",
      "let": { cId: "$subcate.cate", sId: "$subcate._id"},
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                { $eq: [ "$subcate", "$$sId" ] },
                { $eq: [ "$cate", "$$cId" ] },
                
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "subcate.petacate"
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "name": { "$first": "$name" },
      "subcate": { $push: "$subcate" }
    }
  }
])
```

**Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o8GAOrSPERo)**

**Update 1**

`$unwind` default behavior is to remove if an array is null or empty. To prevent it we do

```
{
    "$unwind": {
      path: "$subcate",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  }
```

Note : This may make empty array or empty objects based on the following stages. If you don't need, use `$match` with condition to remove empty array or object

Comment: when subcategory not available then even i want display my shoes in list of array